# Факториал числа выходит за пределы int, long

Tags: java

Нужно посчитать факториал числа.
Когда результат слишком большой, он выходит за пределы `long` или `int`.

Что в этом случае можно сделать?

```
int n = 101;
long res = n;
int count = n - 1;
do {
    res *= count;
    count--;
}
while (count > 0);            
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: пр**е**дел, случа**е**, сд**е**лать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте класс [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) или [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). Ну и какой же факториал без рекурсии :)

```
public static BigInteger getFactorial(BigInteger num) {
  if (num.intValue() == 0) return BigInteger.valueOf(1);
  if (num.intValue() == 1) return BigInteger.valueOf(1);
  return num.multiply(getFactorial(num.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1))));
}
```

Comment: Я тоже сначала написал про BigDecimal, но, насколько можно предположить из описания, на больших числах он начнет откровенно врать, предоставляя исключительно кратные десятке числа. Насколько понимаю, нужен [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply(java.math.BigInteger)), и, конечно, не только ссылкой, но и описанием работы с ним.

Comment: С космическими числами всегда беда.

Comment: @Etki кто начинает откровенное врать? BigInteger? Специальный класс для работы с длинной арифметикой?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov BigDecimal. Если я правильно понял доку, то он хранится integer * (10 ^ integer), что при больших числах (больше, например, Integer.MAX_VALUE), приведет к потерям точности. Я, конечно, могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать массивы, а не просто переменную, и руками переносить разряды.

Comment: Да, согласен... можно и так

Comment: Как академическое упражнение - да. Строки или массивы.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант - использовать BigInteger и заносить значения в ArrayList. При большом количестве вычислений это становится эффективнее рекурсии